# PostgreSQL JSONB versus keeping a separate table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I'm thinking through a database design and I was wondering if anyone could chime in. I have some structured data that I will occasionally be filtering against some somewhat unstructured data. I'm thinking a lot about performance so I'm trying to keep it as denormalized as possible. Do people have opinions about an indexed JSONB column over a separate table? For example:

```
| (smurfs) id | name   | filters (GIN index)                 |
|-------------+--------+-------------------------------------|
|           1 | Papa   | { "color": "blue" }                 |
|           2 | Brainy | { "brain": "big", "color": "blue" } |
```

And I'd query against the indexed JSONB data.

Or:

```
| (smurfs) id | name   |
|-------------+--------+
|           1 | Papa   |
|           2 | Brainy |

| (filters) id | smurf_id | filter_type | filter_value |
|--------------+----------+-------------+--------------|
|            1 |        1 | color       | blue         |
|            2 |        2 | brain       | big          |
|            3 |        2 | color       | blue         |
```

and I'd JOIN the filters with the data for my query.

There's a lot of talk about misuse of JSON in relational databases. Does this fit into that category? Would one be preferable over another from a good design standpoint. Is one more performant? I'm trying to optimize for reads on a large table. Seems like in the second case, I'd have 2 large tables instead of one.

Comment: I would say that this strongly depends on the nature of the columns.  If each row is likely to have the same columns, then you should split them into separate columns.  If the columns have different types, then the EAV method (table method in your description) does not readily support them.  If each row is likely to have different keys from other rows, then JSON might be very appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, I see that my example isn't great because smurfs have a common set of attributes. I won't know ahead of time all the possible filter types.